# Database error "MultiQuery does not support keys_only" in django GAE

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, django-nonrel, djangoappengine

I am using djangoappengine with django non-rel.

```
class Subject(TimeStampedModel):

    class_room = models.ForeignKey( ClassRoom, related_name='class_subject')
    subject = models.CharField( max_length=255)
    tutor = models.ForeignKey( UserProfile, related_name='tutor')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.subject





def quick_delete_subject(request, classroom_id, subject_id):

    if request.method == 'GET':
        classroom = ClassRoom.objects.get(pk=classroom_id)
        school = classroom.school
        school_id = school.pk

    try:
        old_subject = Subject.objects.get(pk=subject_id)
        old_subject.delete()
    except:
        raise

    return HttpResponse('Deleted')
```

But when I try to get delete a subject object in a view I get this error.
The weird thing is sometimes the object gets deleted without any error.

```
Django Version:     1.5.5
Exception Type:     DatabaseError
Exception Value:    MultiQuery does not support keys_only.
```

Comment: Please provide the full stacktrace.

Comment: I am seeing this too. I can workaround by making all queries not keys_only in compiler.py by default but this is not ideal solution